# richfaces 3.3- how to not display richTreeNode

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

```
        <rich:tree
                              ...
            reRender="mainFrm:updateTilesToRender"
            value="#{AssetTreeControl.tree}" var="item" treeNodeVar="treeNode"
            adviseNodeOpened="#{AssetTreeControl.isOpenNodes}">


            <%--i want here if item.toShow == true display the tree node otherwise dont--%>
                <rich:treeNode type="regularNode" 
                    <t:div 
                        style="#{item.toShow == false? 'display:none' : 'visabilty:inline'};hight:1px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.userObject.description}"
                    </t:div>
                </rich:treeNode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nodeFace attribute of rich:tree. Define two rich:treeNode, one with type="visible" and other with type="invisible". Invisible TreeNode is an empty rich:treeNode tag and in the visible node display whatever you like.